# How to get all links in a directory separated by pagination

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The structure of my website is:

```
article manager
    article1link   # on 1st page
    article2link   # on 1st page
    article3link   # on 2nd page
    article4link   # on 2nd page
    article5link   # on 3rd page
    article6link   # on 3rd page
```

I am using the requests and BeautifulSoap module to get the links of `article[1-6]link` by:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

article_manager_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_manager_page,'lxml')
article_list = [article_manager_url + '/' + node.get('href') for node in article_manager_soup.find_all('a') if node.get('href')]
```

But the problem is that I'm able to get only the first two article links on the first page, i.e, `article1link`, `article2link`. When I click on the next page, no parameter are changed so I cannot use the url as a reference. How can I get the remaining links?

Comment: Just on the side note, can I add a regex to `.endswith()`?

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add links then you will have to use `Selenium` because `requests` and `BS` don't execute JavaScript (they don't event read files with JavaScript)

Comment: `.endswith()` doesn't use regex. You will have to use functions from `re` module.